# Многопоточное копирование больших файлов

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Подскажите, каким способом лучше организовать программу для многопоточного копирования файлов большого размера? Не получается правильно объединить скопированные части из разных потоков.

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];
FileSize = new FileInfo(sourceFilePath).Length;
FileSplit(numThreads); //метод розбиває файл на частини по кількості потоків
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread(() => 
    CopyFile(sourceFilePath,  numThreads, (i-1),FileSize));               
    threads[i].Start();
}
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```

Comment: Нет смысла копировать файлы многопоточно, так как файловая система в рамках одного носителя является однозадачной. Если работать с SSD, то прироста производительности не будет, а если с HDD, то возможно даже ее падение из-за затрат времени на перемещение пишущей головки носителя с одного файла на другой и обратно.

Comment: К предыдущему комментарию могу добавить только одно соображение: многопоточное копирование может быть актуально при копировании по сети, когда процесс передачи потока данных от источника к получателю заметно медленнее скорости записи, канал настолько неустойчивый, что проще передавать небольшими фрагментами или источник имеет распределенную структуру типа торрента. В этом случае необходимо передать получателю общий размер файла для резервирования места, а при передаче фрагмента, в дополнение к потоку данных, передавать смещение от начала файла и, опционально, длину данного фрагмента